# Error: Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I have a big problem with a part of my code, which I have spent lots of hours on, trying to understand what I have to do to solve my problem. Well, I have the following .m files and -as the title of my question says- during running the main.m file the error: "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts" occurs.

So, the files are:

- computeCost.m

  ```
  function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)

  m = length(y); % number of training examples

  J(m,1) = 0;

  for k=1:m
      J(:,1) = ((X*theta)-y).^2; 
  end
  %syms k;
  %S = symsum(((X*theta)-y).^2,k,1,m);
  %J = (1/(2*m))*S;
  J(m,1) = (1/(2*m))*J(m,1);
  ```
- gradientDescent.m

  ```
  function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

  m = length(y); % number of training examples
  J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

  for iter = 1:num_iters

  J_history(iter,1) = computeCost(X, y, theta); // HERE IS THE ERROR!!!(1st case)

  end

  end
  ```

Prior to write the above written code I had the following:

- computeCost.m

  ```
  function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)

  m = length(y); % number of training examples

  J = 0;

  for k=1:m
      J(:) = ((X(k)*theta(k))-y(k)).^2;
  end
  %syms k;
  %S = symsum(((X*theta)-y).^2,k,1,m);
  %J = (1/(2*m))*S;
  J(m) = (1/(2*m))*J(m);
  ```
- gradientDescent.m

  ```
  function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)

  m = length(y); % number of training examples
  J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);

  for iter = 1:num_iters

  J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta); // HERE IS THE ERROR(2nd case)

  end

  end
  ```

When I had the last code I was facing another error: "in an assignment a( ) = b the number of elements in a and b must be the same.". So, I did the necessary-in my opinion- changes and I created the code I presented firstly. I do not know which one of the two above mentioned aprroaches is better.

My task: To complete the code in the file computeCost.m, which
is a function that computes J(theta).

Hint: The variables X and y are not scalar values, but matrices whose rows represent the examples from the training set. As well the gradientDescent.m file is executed after computeCost.m file's execution. Let the parameters, functions and in general all mentioned unknown data be given data from a different .txt file.

I am desperated and I would appreciate if someone could fix my code(and my problem). Well, what do I have to do??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Error is on which line and in which function?

Comment: I edited my post. So, I am indicating now by comments where the errors(both cases) occur.

Comment: Could you post the error message MATLAB gives. The information you have doesn't indicate where in the `computeCost` function error occurs.

Comment: It does not indicate where the error occurs in the computeCost function because I made some edits and I solved the error in this function. The only error is in gradientDescent function. Semantically the program may be right, but some details(lexical, I think) are those which generate the errors. That's why I have done some edits on the posted code and the errors are almost the same(either "Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts" or  "in an assignment a( ) = b the number of elements in a and b must be the same."

Answer (score 0):

`J_history(:,iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta);` should do the trick. You are assigning a column vector, output of `computeCost`, to a variable `J_history`. This means the storage variable has to be accessed column-wise, provided `computeCost` always outputs the same number of columns. If that is not the case you'll have to look into cell arrays.

This error occurs because you are trying to store something that has more dimensions than the storage container. See it like you are trying to store your 24 beer bottles in a crate for 6 bottles, that won't fit. (technically the 6 need to be on one line to fit the example, but it'll do).

So, what you do when you see this error is:

- Select `db stop if error` in the editor tab
- Check the size of the thing you are storing
- Check the size of the container
- Match the two if possible, if not, think of another solution.

Comment: Your answer was very useful! But my problems did not stop...The nature of my problem has been changed and therefore I have written a new post about it. Just one step far from the success!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726709/error-assignment-has-more-non-singleton-rhs-dimensions-than-non-singleton-subs

Comment: If this answer did solve your (initial) problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of the post. This signals that you have solved this problem and no longer need help. I will look into the other question as well.